# Store value of a subquery - mongoose

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, mongoose

**What im doing:**

When I call `getData()` the backend server `.find()` all my data.

**My documents:**

My `test` document has an `_id` a `name` and `stuff` fields. The `stuff` field contains the `_id` to the `data` document.

My `data` document has an `_id` and a `age` field

**My goal:**

When I send the data to the frontend I don´t want the `stuff` field to appear with the `_id`, I want it to appear with the `age` field from the corresponding`data`.

**What I have:**

```
router.route('/data').get((req, res) => {
    Test.find((err, aval) => {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
        else{

            var result = [];

            aval.forEach(e => {
                var age;
                // Get the age, only 1
                Data.findById(e.stuff, 'age', function (err, a) {
                    age = a.age;
                });

                result.push({name: e.name, age: age});
            });

            res.json(result);
        }

    });
});
```

I find all the `test` documents then, for each one of them, I find the `age` and put the result in the array. Finaly I send the `result` array.

**My problem:**

The age field on my result array is always undefined, why? Any solutions?

**UPDATE 1 - The schemas**

The `test` schema

```
var TestSchema = new Schema(
  {
    stuff: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Data', required: true},
    name: {type: String, required: true}
  }
);
```

The `data` schema

```
 var DataSchema = new Schema(
  {
    age: {type: Number, required: true}
  }
);
```

Comment: Can you add your model structure so i can see the relationship

Comment: @decodedxclusive I added the schemas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
router.route('/data').get((req, res) => {
    Test.find({})
    .populate('stuff')
    .exec((err, aval) => {
        if (err) console.log(err); 
        res.json(aval); 
     });
 });
```

Mongoose model has a populate property that uses the value in the model attribute definition to get data matching the _id from another model.

Answer (score 0):

It's a scop problem with your code try this out :

```
Data.findById(e.stuff, 'age', function (err, a) {

  result.push({name: e.name, age:  a.age});

});
```

But as a better solution think to use the Aggregation Framework